# c++; array and std dev; easy fix I'm sure

Tags: c++

Now I can't get this to compile.  Here's the code...reading in from the keyboard a group of numbers and ouput the std dev.  Error code: LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'c:\users\svc-student\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Lab7ProgProj4\Debug\Lab7ProgProj4.exe'

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
double std_dev( double a [], int x );
const int MAX= 100;

int main ()
{
    double next;
    int index = 0;
    double a[MAX];

    cout << "I will give you the std deviation of a group of numbers less than "<< MAX << endl;
    cin >> next;
    while ((cin>>next) && (index < MAX))
    {
        a[index] = next;
        index++;
        cin >> next;
    }
    std_dev ( a , index );
}
double std_dev( double a [], int x )
{
    double average, y;
    double sum = 0;
    int i;
    for( i = 0; i < x;i++ )
        {
        sum = sum + a[i];
        }
    average = sum / x;
    sum = 0;
    for( i = 0; i < x; i++ )
    {
        y =pow((a[i]-average),2);
        //cout << s<<" ";
        sum = sum + y;
    }
cout <<(sqrt (sum / x));

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Most likely the program was still running and therefore could not be overwritten by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to do with C++. Program compiles.

The error: cannot open file 'c:\users\svc-student\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Lab7ProgProj4\Debug\Lab7ProgProj4.exe'

Check that you can write files there, that you are not out of space.

Comment: Ok.  How about the code.  When I could compile I couldn't get any output and I don't know why